# Laravel how to automate drop tables then import sql file then apply migration?

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, laravel-migrations

Because of different namming conventions than Laravel in an other database I need to automate this process in Laravel :

1. Drop all tables
2. import sql dump file
3. replay my migration which rename columns, FKs etc...

What could I do to achieve this ?

php artisan migrate:fresh --seed command would not work because it would import sql on last.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write a [custom command](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/artisan#writing-commands) for this task.

1. Create a command: `php artisan make:command MigrateDatabase`
2. Open the command file `app/Console/Commands/MigrateDatabase.php`
3. Change the command name i.e. to this: `protected $signature = 'migrate_database:migrate';`
4. Write these lines in the `handle()` method:

   ```
   public function handle(){
       Artisan::call('migrate:reset', ['--force' => true]);
       DB::unprepared(file_get_contents('full/path/to/dump.sql'));
       Artisan::call('migrate');
   }
   ```
5. Call the command: `php artisan migrate_database:migrate`

**Be careful before run this in production, i did not tested. (And of course it will drop your db)**

Comment: Thank you very much exactly what I was searching for ! 